# Virtualbox Port-Forwarding Does nothing when SSH connection is attempted

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I recently created an Ubuntu 22.04 VM with virtualbox. Its network setup consists of a Host-Only Network & and a NAT. I recently set it up to allow ssh connections on the private network through setting up port-forwarding on the VM on the NAT adapter (not through the Network manager menu)
[Just like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mDi.png) .

This worked, and I was able to SSH onto my VM. However, when I went onto my router dashboard and tried to setup port forwarding to a public IP and then tried to ssh onto my routers public IP, it did not give any error, but did not prompt for a password either. It just showed nothing.

I have disabled and even removed my firewall, I tried port-forwarding with other devices successfully. The only thing I suspect might cause an issue would be my fail2ban config, but the other device I used previously, (my miniPC) worked just fine with it. Does anyone know what caused this issue?

Thank you

-Cyberslash

Comment: I am double port forwarding I guess :)

Comment: What do you see in Wireshark packet captures? Does the router actually forward the "forwarded" SSH (TCP) packets back to you? If it does – what IP address do they appear to come _from_?